# Problema executar projeto Java Web

Tags: java, java-ee

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém já teve esse mesmo erro usando JavaWeb ? não consigo executar meu projeto

Answer (score 1):

Reveja as configurações do seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]